# WAS 8.5.5.7 : JAX-RPC / JAX-WS / APACHE SOAP

Tags: jax-ws, apache-axis, ibm-was, jax-rpc

My compagny change the version of WAS 7 by 8. We expose some WS by the RPC router of was which isn't support with the new version. I want to have your advice on the possibility to create the following architecture to resolve the problem. Problem is : We doesn't want to change the url of service expose by RPCRouter (../servlet/router), in the futur we will pass on WAS 9, JAX-RPC will be deprecated, so i prefere to developp with JAX-WS IBM or Axis2.

Below the architecture :[archi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INn4W.png)

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RPC is deprecated in v9.  What this means is that it may (yes, MAY) be taken out of the product in v9 + 2 (ie v11) or later.  For instance, features deprecated in v7, may be removed from the product in v9.  (There were almost 8y between 7.0.0.0 and 9.0.0.0)

In other words, you have a really, really long runway here.